# Git: Why am I not seeing latest changes on a file that I have checked out?

Tags: git

I am working on a local branch and I am aware that a file I will have to make changes to but have yet changed has been changed by other developers. I want those changes before I start to change the file myself. I can see that the file has been changed in, for example, the web-based tool that shows our git repo. I have done things like git fetch remotes/origin/develop (which is the name of the branch all developers push to) and then a git checkout changedFile.java I still do not see the latest changes when I do a git log or use gitk. What am I missing?

EDIT: What I think is being said is that if you have a local branch other than develop you can't update a file on that branch from the remote develop?

EDIT: the git checkout origin/develop -- path/to/changedFile.java did as far as I can tell exactly what I want and let me motivate that further: I was working on my local branch and the remote develop (which is not the name of the local branch I am working on) deviated. I am about to change one of the files and that particular file changed. It seems to me I could use the version of the file without the later changes and do a merge later or get the changes and probably have an easier merge. So the checkout worked and my only question is, Why is this ever the *wrong* thing to do?

Comment: What does `git status` say about the file? Are you on the right branch? (`git fetch` doesn't pull code from other branches into your working directory)

Comment: i do the fetch while i am in my local branch. are you saying i need to be in develop to see these changes and if so, what would be the method to update the file that has changes? Git status has nothing to say about the file i tried to update but just that my branch has diverged.

Comment: try `git checkout develop -- changedFile.java`

Comment: If you already have a local branch checked out, you need to merge develop branch changes into you branch, possibly with fast-forward.

Comment: So something like `git merge develop` may help... (possible option `--no-commit` to revise changes)

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

If you just want to *view* the file, use `git show`, e.g.:

```
git show origin/develop:changedFile.java
```

If you use `git checkout origin/develop -- changedFile.java`, that will extract it through your index into your work-tree, but this is often *not* a good idea.

#### What to know up front about commits and the index/staging-area

Git is all about *commits*.  Commits aren't files, although commits do in effect *contain* files.  More precisely, each commit contains a complete snapshot of *every* file, in the state it had at the time you (or whoever) made the commit. (Even this isn't quite right.)

In order to make *new* commits, Git provides you two places to work on files.  One of these, called the *work-tree*, is pretty obvious.  Files in your work-tree have their ordinary form that your computer deals with all the time.  They can be read, written, updated-in-place, appended-to, whatever.  In other words, the work-tree is where you do your work.

For various reasons, Git lets you have, in your work-tree, files that *won't* be committed.  These are *untracked* files.  Git does nothing with untracked files, except constantly complain that they are untracked.  To shut it up, you can list particular untracked files in `.gitignore`, which doesn't make Git *ignore* them really, it just shuts it up about their untracked-ness, and makes it not `git add` them if you use a mass "add everything" operation.  (Note that if a file is already tracked, listing it in `.gitignore` has no effect.)

There's another copy of *every tracked file*.  This extra copy, called the *index* or *staging-area* copy, is in fact how Git knows that it's a tracked file.  These copies are always present, and in fact, when you do make a new commit, Git makes the commit from the *index* copies, not from the work-tree copies!  This is why Git is constantly requiring you to `git add` things: the `git add` command means "copy from work-tree to index".  It only does that copying at the moment you say `git add`; if you change the file again, you have to re-copy it again.

When you run `git commit`, Git packages up the current index contents (yet another new copy of every file!), your name and email address and the current time, the commit message you write, and the hash ID of the current or `HEAD` commit.  It then makes a *new* commit from all of this stuff, and makes the current branch name (stored in `HEAD`) point to the new commit you just made.  This commit is (mostly) permanent and (completely) read-only, so it saves what you have done forever, or until you explicitly make it go away (and even then Git tends to hang on to it for at least another 30 days "just in case").

We can draw your commits, and all the other commits, by writing down their big ugly hash IDs and connecting each commit to its parent with an arrow.  We use a bigger arrow from the current branch name:

```
... <-194ab72  <-c309ac4   <-- develop
```

Since hash IDs are big and clumsy, we can represent these with single uppercase letters instead, as long as we never need to write down more than 26 commits:

```
... <-G <-H   <-- develop
```

Each commit remembers its parent; but since commits are unchangeable, the parents don't remember their children.  Git therefore has to (and does) always work backwards.  The branch *name*, `develop`, stores the newest commit you have on your `develop`.  To make a new commit, you just add it to your chain:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- develop
```

(since the internal arrows always go backwards and never change, we can pretty much stop drawing them now).

#### `git show` can show just about anything

Running `git show` with no arguments shows you your current commit, by printing its log message, and then comparing it to its parent.  This converts the snapshot into "changes since the previous snapshot".

Running `git show origin/develop` shows the commit that is at the tip of `origin/develop`.  It does the same thing: prints the log message, then compares the commit to its parent, to see what changed since its parent.

Running `git show origin/develop:path/to/file.txt` shows you the contents of `path/to/file.txt` in the commit specified by `origin/develop`.

#### Now that you know the above, here's how to use it

You have been working on some code.  Maybe you have made commits, and maybe not.  You have some changes in the work-tree.  Someone else has made some *other* change, in some other repository, and committed it (making whole snapshots) and pushed *their* commit(s) so that it's in `origin/develop`.

You ran `git fetch origin` which updated your `origin/develop` to record their new commit.  Let's draw that:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- develop
            \
             J   <-- origin/develop
```

What you can and should do is commit your own code now.  Let's draw that, too:

```
...--G--H--I--K   <-- develop
            \
             J   <-- origin/develop
```

Now you can use `git merge`.  What `git merge` does is *combine* your work with their work, and—at least in this case, and as long as Git itself thinks the merge worked—make a *new* commit that saves, as a (mostly) permanent and (completely) unchangeable snapshot, the result of that combining:

```
...--G--H--I--K--M   <-- develop
            \ __/
             J   <-- origin/develop
```

Or, instead, you can use `git rebase`.  What `git rebase` does is *copy* commits, and after it has finished copying them to new-and-improved commits, abandon the originals.  (This is where the normal permanence of commits gets undone.)  If you copy your commit `K` to a new-and-improved `K'` whose parent is `J`, we can draw that like this:

```
...--G--H--I--K   [abandoned]
            \
             J   <-- origin/develop
              \
               K'  <-- develop
```

#### Merge and rebase both use the merge machinery and do merge-as-a-verb

The interesting thing about this copying process is that it uses the *same* underlying code to merge *file* changes that `git merge` uses.  What's different is the so-called *merge base* computation, though for this particular simple case the merge base is commit `I` in both cases anyway.

When Git goes to merge things, it finds which files are changed since that merge base, and figures out "what you did" (to those files) and "what they did" (to the same files).

If you and they changed all-different files, everything is really easy.  Git just takes all the unchanged files straight from the base, all *your* changed files in from your commit, and all *their* changed files from their commit.  If you both changed the *same* file, Git tries to combine your changes and their changes.  As long as those changes don't (seem to) overlap, Git will think it has combined them successfully.

This action, of combining two sets of changes since a common starting point (shared commit), is what Git means by *merge* when used as a verb.  Note that *merge* can also be used as an adjective, though: a *merge commit* is a commit that records two parent commits, like `M` in the example above.  The adjective even becomes a noun: this commit is *a merge*.

Merging combines commits, and the merged branches are just that—branches—even if they have no names.  Suppose, for instance, you find that merge commit `M` is perfect.  It does exactly what you want.  You can `git push` that to `origin`, after which the picture becomes:

```
...--G--H--I--K--M   <-- origin/develop, develop
            \ __/
             J
```

There is a branch in this, even though there is no branch *name* pointing to commit `J`.  Commit `M` points to commit `J` (it has *two* parents, `K` and `J`).  As a merge commit, `M` serves to tie two branches together.

#### Should you rebase, or merge?

This question doesn't have a single correct answer.  Rebasing makes things look nicer in the future, as if you didn't even *start* on your changes until after they finished theirs.  Once you've abandoned your original commit `K` in favor of the revised/improved `K'`, we can turn this drawing:

```
...--G--H--I--K   [abandoned]
            \
             J   <-- origin/develop
              \
               K'  <-- develop
```

into:

```
...--G--H--I   K'  <-- develop
            \ /
             J   <-- origin/develop
```

Then we can drop the little tick mark ("prime") symbol and push your commit so that `origin/develop` now incorporates your commit:

```
...--G--H--I--J--K   <-- origin/develop, develop
```

and history looks so simple, compared to the merge version.  But it's not the actual history, it's a revised / cleaned-up history.  This is good (easy to work with) and bad (if the revising broke something).

#### What if you're not done yet?

If you aren't actually finished with your changes yet, rebasing gives you the opportunity to finish them later.  Or, you can simply not merge yet.  As long as you haven't `git push`-ed a commit, you can use `git commit --amend` to *seem to* change the current / newest one in-place.  You just work as usual, `git add` your files, and then run `git commit --amend` instead of `git commit`.  Git takes your current commit and "shoves it aside", making your new commit have, as its parent commit, the commit *before* your current commit.  If `K` is your current commit, we can draw this as:

```
       K   [abandoned]
      /
...--J--K'   <-- develop
```

You can repeat this as many times as you like; each one shoves another commit out of the way and inserts the new one at the end:

```
      K   [abandoned]
     /
     | K'   [abandoned]
     |/
...--J--K''' <-- develop
      \
       K''  [abandoned]
```

Note that you can do this with commits you have not yet `git merge`-ed (if `K`'s parent is `I`, because you didn't `git rebase` either).  If you *have* run `git merge`, though, `git commit --amend` won't do you any good, because the newest commit will be your merge commit.

(If you *have* merged, but not pushed, you can "rebase away" the merge.  When rebase copies commits, it explicitly *skips* merge commits.  This gets a little bit—or even a lot—tricky in some cases, though.)

#### Future reading

Note that Git offers an *interactive* rebase mode.  Using interactive rebase, you can re-arrange and combine commits, as long as they're un-pushed (un-published) commits.  This means you can safely commit in-progress snapshots, even of tiny changes, for any particular purpose.  Later, when they are really ready, you can use an interactive rebase to combine them all into one big commit, or several small but standalone commits.  You can make it look like you knew what you were doing all along, even if you had to try a bunch of things and undo some of them.

Comment: I am not sure if the answer is in there, if reading this entire thing is necessary to understand why I can't get the latest version of a file from origin (which seems like a very natural thing) or what.

Comment: You can *view* the file, if you wish, with `git show <revspec>:<path>`. You can also extract the file from another commit with `git checkout` but this will overwrite the index and work-tree versions, which is why you need to know a lot of the above. Git has a well-earned reputation for being beginner-unfriendly! In general, though, the way to work is not to worry about it so much yet: let the later merge or rebase take care of this. I'll add the `git show` though, at the front.

Comment: The problem I am having is that it seems like, while on a branch I created about a month ago, another file has been changed, as I mentioned. The first question is, is it expected behavior that I can't get this change onto the branch I am on?

Comment: That's ... hard to answer without the proper background. You can make any file look like anything you want: just replace the work-tree version of the file with a new version of the file, `git add` it to copy it to the index, and `git commit`. You can extract any commit you like, at any time, though if you have unsaved work in the index or work-tree, you should commit it (or use `git stash`, which commits it) so that you can get it back. You can, if you have Git version 2.6 or later, use `git worktree add` to add a whole new work-tree.

Comment: But (I'm out of room in the previous comment) if you work "against" the way the Git designers envisioned people working, you will find Git even more frustrating than everyone always finds it at first. The general idea is to make a lot of small commits, and then use tools like rebase and merge to hammer them into the final shape you would like them to have. Each branch can be used for independent tasks; `git merge` will do its best to combine them later.

Comment: I have been working on a branch foo for a month. This involves changes to existing files and some new files. I also know that a file changedFile.java exists on the origin and I sure want to get the latest version of changedFile.java before I start changing it, too. I would like to stay on foo. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes: `git fetch origin`; commit your current work; then rebase (i.e., copy) your commit(s) upon `origin/<branch>`. See the section above about rebasing.

Comment: Okay: so while on foo, simply checking out remotes/origin/develop/changedFile.java should NOT work, right?

Comment: That's a slightly broken (in terms of Git's syntax anyway) expression naming a file, not a commit—so, yes, you can't check it out that way. You *can* check out individual files from specific commits, but this overwrites the index copy of the file too, which is surprising at first. It also does not move the current commit, so it's usually the wrong thing to do.

Comment: In Eclipse it looks like you can replace a file with HEAD which may be what I want to. If it is, how can this be done from the command line. If it isn't, what is happening in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm not sure what Eclipse is doing. HEAD is not a file, though; HEAD is a special name (so special that if the file goes missing, Git declares the repository to no longer be a repository!), normally containing the name of the current branch. `git checkout <branchname>` extracts the commit that is at the tip of the specified branch, and if/when that succeeds, writes that branch name into `HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

Despite @torek's answer is comprehensive and fully explains how to work with git, I would suggest you to *visualize* your commits tree with all branches first, and expect files contents in a particular branch and commit.

For me the best tool to do this is [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) — use `gitk --all` to see the actual tree of commits in the *local* repository. But depending on your platform you may prefer other GUI clients/